# SMTP Authentication issue on a postfix/dovecot setup

Tags: debian, postfix, smtp, email-server, dovecot

I have just setup my debian mailserver using postfix, dovecot and SASL as explained in this excellent [tutorial](http://serion.co.nz/howto/howto-setup-mailserver-using-postfix-mysql-dovecot-postfixadmin-amavis-new). I have used postfixadmin to setup a virtual list of aliases for sending user@domain.com to their email (for example, user@gmail.com). This works for receiving but for sending out with their new email I need to authenticate them. Question is, where does this authentication come from? Because they're aliases they do not have an account on the server! Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

You need to do three things, create a file (or DB) with `domain   username:password` style entries, postmap (or create a query that will find the info) that file, then tell postfix to use those entries when sending to servers who need them:

> smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes # you should have this already
>   smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/smtp_sasl_passwd # this is the postmap variety 
>   smtp_sasl_password_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_sasl_passwd # MySQL version

Read more [Here](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_enable)

Comment: I have smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes, but not without the d!

Comment: Yeah, just create a table, and follow the model of other tables and queries.. I'm trying to find out what postfix wants in terms of responses.

Comment: Cool thanks. I'm probably going to use the postmap just because our Mysql server is not localhost. Trying not to complicate things!

Comment: There's something for you to follow here: http://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/postfix-as-relay-to-a-smtp-requiring-authentication/ in the comments :)

Comment: BTW, the link in the comments was a mysql statement, what I wrote in the answer will work fine for the postmap command.

Comment: Yea I figured. I've set this up as that post does, but keep getting auth failed. Do you think its the md5-digest mechanism maybe?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed

Comment: Hmm, it's quite possibly this: http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_filter

Comment: Just to confirm, in sasl-passwords I do put the password as plain text, then run postmap which hashes it in the db it outputs?

Comment: All correct, if you want, you can even make the file root root, that way the file with the unhashed passwords is more secure. The problem you have may also be that the mechanism you're trying to auth with on the other side isn't present..

Comment: That's what I've read, although I'm using gmail which is quite popular so looking to see if that's a common problem. I did notice when using telnet to test and calling EHLO mail.domain.com it attempts over plain login (I think): `250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN`, shouldn't this be MD5 DIGEST?

Comment: Very possibly, you should test to gmail and see what they respond to your ehlo.

Comment: Hmm, I've just noticed that changing the relayhost option in postfix is causing everything to stop! Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7971/discussion-between-nickw-and-ing0)